# Works in SQLFiddle Not in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlfiddle

When I run this Query in SQL Fiddle it runs perfectly:

```
;with cte as 
(SELECT 
 analysisvalue.analysisid, 
 heatname, 
 analysistime, 
 sampletype,
 grade, 
 productid, 
 element, 
 value 
 FROM 
 dbo.AnalysisValue 
 INNER JOIN 
 dbo.CAnalysis 
 ON 
 dbo.AnalysisValue.AnalysisID = dbo.CAnalysis.AnalysisID
 WHERE 
 heatname = 'A7M0066' 
 )
 SELECT 
      * 
 FROM 
 S_analysis s
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 analysistime
 FROM cte
 ORDER BY analysisid desc
 ) c
 WHERE s.heat_no = 'A7M0066' OR
 (s.analysis_datetime BETWEEN c.analysistime AND DATEADD(hh, 2, c.analysistime ))
```

However when I run it in SQL Server 2012, I receive this error with the leading semi-colon:

```
Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near ';'.
```

And this error when without the semicolon:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.
```

Comment: I don't think there's a need of using **WITH**

Comment: @Luv After removing with I receive the error:Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Comment: My BAD. Was trying to help you.

Comment: When I took a quick look at the msdn documentation, it had column names after the alias.  Yours doesn't.  However, I think the most important lesson is to use the appropriate tool for the job.  For sql server, that's sql server, not sqlfiddle.

Comment: Is this the ONLY code logic being run? Is there something above the `;with ...` that could be the real issue?

Comment: @Love2Learn This is the only code and/or logic in the query window

Comment: If you copy and paste this code into SSMS in SQL Server 2012 and click the check mark (Parse) button, do you get the same error?

Comment: If you get an error when you remove the semi-colon before the with there must be something preceding it. You are most likely missing an end parenthesis somewhere which is causing the compiler to read the `WITH` as the start of a query hint, rather than the start of a CTE. What code do you have before `;WITH`? There must be something (even if it is something like `SET NOCOUNT ON`) otherwise you would not get a syntax error when the semi-colon is removed.

Comment: As a side note, have a read of [this blog by Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons), it should hopefully change the way you think about terminating statements properly. People tend to think they have to use `;WITH`, however if the last statement is terminated properly you do not have to worry about preceding certain key words with a semi-colon. You can just start your CTE using `WITH` as you would with any other statement.

Comment: please link the working fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a CTE, you could use a #temp table and see if the query is valid:

```
SELECT 
analysisvalue.analysisid, 
heatname, 
analysistime, 
sampletype,
grade, 
productid, 
element, 
value 
INTO #temptable
FROM 
dbo.AnalysisValue 
INNER JOIN 
dbo.CAnalysis 
ON 
dbo.AnalysisValue.AnalysisID = dbo.CAnalysis.AnalysisID
WHERE 
heatname = 'A7M0066';

SELECT * 
FROM 
S_analysis s
CROSS JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 analysistime
FROM #temptable
ORDER BY analysisid desc
) c
WHERE s.heat_no = 'A7M0066' OR
(s.analysis_datetime BETWEEN c.analysistime AND DATEADD(hh, 2, c.analysistime ))
```